# Vaadin beanItemContainer property is array: how to get the data from the array

Tags: arrays, grid, vaadin

I want to get data from an array into a vaadin grid. 
Here are some relevant parts of my code:

From the Grid's builder-class

```
Grid grid = new Grid();
for(int i = 0; i<numberColumns; i++){       
            String propertyId = "deliveryList[" + i + "]";
            grid.addColumn(propertyId);
}
```

In the base class:

```
public class DeliveryVO {
  private Integer[] deliveryList;

  public Integer[] getDeliveryList() {
    return deliveryList;
  }
...
```

and in the view where the grid should be displayed:

```
DeliveryVO deliveryVO1 = new deliveryVO(12);
final BeanItemContainer<DeliveryVO> beanItemContainer = new BeanItemContainer<DeliveryVO>(DeliveryVO.class);
beanItemContainer.addBean(deliveryVO1);

final Grid grid = new xGrid.Builder()
        .setNumberColumns(12)
        .setTimeGroup(TIME_GROUP.HOURLY).build();
grid.setContainerDataSource(beanItemContainer);
...
addComponent(grid);
```

When i try to run this i get the following error:

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Found at least one column in Grid that does not exist in the given container: deliveryList[0] with the header "Delivery List[0]"

I can get data in the grid when i use the propertyId of an attribute in de DeliveryVO-class, but i cannot acces the data from the array... Can someone help we with getting this array-data into the Grid?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to this question can be found at:

https://vaadin.com/forum#!/thread/9934386

Answer (score 0):

When using BeanItemContainer it expects the colums to be properties of your VO or bean class of the container. In your case the best option is to use a column generator where you can write specific logic of extracting and building your column component from array values. Alternatively you can write your own container which extends BeanItemContainer and then override getContainerValue method for data extraction logic.